# Thread first job first python

Tags: python, multithreading, sequence

```
#threads
lock = threading.Lock()
t1 = threading.Thread(target=job1, args = (lock, )).start() 
t2 = threading.Thread(target=job2, args = (lock, )).start()
```

I am having two threads which are for job1 and job2 respectively.
Both are scheduled at the same time initially.

Job1 and Job2 are rescheduled at a interval of 10 seconds and 60 seconds respectively (recursively) .

But some time job1 runs first and some times job2 runs first. This happens after every seconds.

[image]

I want somehow job1 should be executed before job2.

so is there a solution?

The time taken by job1 is around less than a second
Where as job2 needs around  4 to 5 seconds to complete the task.

Comment: Why are you using 2 separate threads then if they can't run at the same time? If you make it one thread it's trivial to make sure 1 always runs first.

Comment: Job1 will run at 1 minute frequency and Job2 runes at a frequency of 10 sec . Every Minute both are scheduled to run at a same time. At that time Job1 should run first and Job2 should run next because data from job1 is input data for job2 in making few important decision .